# Android: How are call details compared to saved contacts

Tags: android, sqlite, call, contacts

I am creating an app for which I need to know the Algorithm that is used to compare Call Details with the Contacts that are saved in any phone.
For example: If the phone number of an incoming call is +91xxxxxxxxxx and one of the saved contacts is 0xxxxxxxxxx against a name "Mike" (+91 is the country code for India) and "xxxxxxxxxx" is same in both the cases, the call records show the name "Mike" and the number even though the comparison should ideally fail owing to the difference of "+91" and "0" in the number. I need to know how this algorithm works. 
At first I came up with an idea to extract the last 10 digits of any number and compare them, but then I realized that not all countries have phone numbers of 10 digits. Is it?

Please suggest a way.

Comment: Can you define your purpose of doing this more clearly ? I mean why you want to do this.

Comment: I want to build a custom call records app. That's why I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it will be to compare the characters in reverse and succeed if it matches *most part* of the number. To decide on what is *most part*, is dependent on the application you develop. I guess this is how the caller ID's too work.